# Wiremock - dynamic mapping of response values

Tags: mocking, templating, wiremock, stubbing, wiremock-standalone

I am attempting to use Wiremock standalone with global response templating to dynamically map an input value (`user id`) with a response value (`username`).

My issue in summary is: *unable to fetch a value from `transformerParameters.*` dynamically*.

I have this in the response mapping:

```json
{
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "transformers": [
      "response-template"
    ],
    "transformerParameters": {
      "usernameMapping": {
        "1": "foo",
        "2": "bar",
        "3": "baz"
      }
    },
    "jsonBody": {
      "id": "{{request.pathSegments.[1]}}",
      "username": "{{parameters.usernameMapping.2}}"
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to populate the `username` field in the JSON response based dynamically on the input user ID, by using the JSON map under `transformerParameters.usernameMapping`.

I have tried the following for the `username` field:

- `{{parameters.usernameMapping.2}}` <-- works but hardcoded so does not solve our problem
- `{{parameters.usernameMapping[request.pathSegments.[1]]}}` <-- breaks
- `{{parameters.usernameMapping[{{request.pathSegments.[1]}}]}}` <-- breaks
- `{{parameters.usernameMapping.{{request.pathSegments.[1]}}}}` <-- breaks
- `{{parameters.usernameMapping.[userId]}}` <-- *(`userId` assigned previously)* does not break but prints nothing

I've set up an example repo that quickly recreates my setup and problem, which you can clone from here: https://github.com/francocm/wiremock-template-value-mappings

Am I missing something? I'm trying to avoid writing custom extensions or compiling custom versions of Wiremock, and it feels like I am doing a trivial mistake here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Update - Solution

Use `lookup` in this manner:

- `{{lookup parameters.usernameMapping userId}}`

The git repo has been updated with the working version: https://github.com/francocm/wiremock-template-value-mappings/blob/main/stubs/mappings/example-get-user.json